# Downloading a Report Viewer report to PDF with Powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to call a report server report with parameters and save it as PDF. It works fine in a browser. The PDF file is saved, but I can't choose where to save it.

I'm trying to use Powershell to archieve it.

```
$URI = "http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReportname%2fTemp&rs:Format=PDF&Guid=parameter1&StartDate=01-02-2018&StartTime=07:00&EndDate=01-02-2018&EndTime=17:00"

$Outputfile = "C:\temp\test.pdf"

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -OutFile $Outputfile -UseDefaultCredentials -TimeoutSec 30)
```

The Powershell code downloads a PDF with the correct layout, but no data. It says "No data available". Any ideas?

Comment: Try to download this test .pdf document:
https://s21.q4cdn.com/374334112/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf
I was able to download this test pdf quite easily
Could be that the document which are you trying to download is somehow protected.
For example, I have tried to download one pdf document from my DropBox page, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: That works fine. So it must be something to do with transfering SSRS parameters

Comment: If you run the URL directly in a browser.. does it work? The way the parameters are passed could be the issue.

Comment: Yes, it work directly in a browser. If I use wget it also gives me a PDF with no avaiable data, except from the layout and some text that I habe inserted in the report. In the top of the report I have inserted the parameters as an expression, so they are passed corretly.